# Друзья, нужна помощь. Знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Только теперь Юра почувствовал, как похолодало и сразу вспомнил, что свитер оставил на даче. 
В предложении допущена пунктуационная ошибка, судя по ответам. Буду благодарен ,если укажете - где и расскажете - почему.  * доп. вопрос/ а нужны ли тире в предыдущем предложении? )
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Только теперь Юра **почувствовал**, как похолодало, **и сразу вспомнил**, что свитер оставил на даче.

Союз И соединяет сказуемые, придаточное предложение относится к первому сказуемому и обособляется.

2) Буду благодарен, если укажете **где** и расскажете **почем**у.

Обычно одно союзное слово не отделяется запятой (только при особой интонации), здесь  особого интонационного выделения союзных слов не требуется; кроме того, наличие союза И затрудняет такое обособление.

Союз И соединяет однородные сказуемые.